# How to handle dependency injection with WPF with multiple pages and navigation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, .net-5

#### I've been trying to do the following thing in WPF:

- A window with a **login-page** and a **home-page**.
- Upon successfully authenticating a user, the window should display the home-page.
- It should work by using the native WPF dependency injection framework.

#### But also...

- There might be a page 3, 4, 5 and each of these pages should be able to call one another.
- And maybe each of these pages could have pages inside them that can also call each other.
- So the solution should be able to work with nested pages and navigations if possible.

#### What I have:

So, after looking for solutions in the stack forum I ended up with this composition approach.

Starting by the **App.xaml**, all services and viewmodels are initialized and the main window receives its viewmodel by injection:

```cs
private void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();

    //ViewModels
    services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
    services.AddSingleton<AuthViewModel>();
    services.AddSingleton<HomeViewModel>();
}
private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var mainWindow = serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
    mainWindow.DataContext = serviceProvider.GetService<MainViewModel>();
    mainWindow.Show();
}
```

Then, the mainViewModel receives by injection every other viewmodel and stores them in a property.

```cs
public class MainViewModel 
{
    public IPageViewModel SelectedPage {get; set; } //PropertyChanged() removed for brevity.
    public ObservableCollection<IPageViewModel> Pages {get; set;} 

    public MainViewModel(AuthViewModel authViewModel, HomeViewModel homeViewModel)
    {
        this.Pages = new ObservableCollection<IPageViewModel>()  { authViewModel, homeViewModel};
        this.SelectedPage = this.Pages.First();
    }
}
```

All page viewmodels inherit from this interface so they can be retrieved from the collection by name and then added as the SelectedPage when needed.

```cs
public interface IPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
}
```

The window has a content control with a property content bound to the SelectedPage so it's updated.

```xml
<Window>
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPage}" />
</Window>
```

And it knows which view to use for each viewmodel by these data templates.

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AuthViewModel}">
        <views:AuthView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HomeViewModel}">
        <views:HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

But then... I noticed that this won't work, I can only call changes on the SelectedPage from within the mainViewModel.

```cs
public class AuthViewModel  : BaseViewModel
{
    public AuthViewModel() { }

    public void AttemptLogin() {
        // how
        SelectedPage = Pages[1];
    }
}
```

#### Issues

I could perhaps inject the mainviewmodel in all child models, but that would not look good and in fact from the start a lot of things are kind of a mess.

For example, I have to:

- Add a service viewmodel for every viewmodel I create to the app.xaml.
- Add each one of them as a parameter of the mainwindow viewmodel which looks ugly.

I'm probably doing this very wrong, I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible solutions. A simple one is to introduce an event.

I also recommend to move and restrict the responsibility to select view models to the `MainViewModel`. Other page models should not be aware of the flow like who selects who. Otherwise this would add a too tight coupling, which is avoidable at this point.

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
  public IPageViewModel SelectedPage { get; set; }
  private Dictionary<string, IPageViewModel> Pages { get; } 

  public MainViewModel(AuthViewModel authViewModel, HomeViewModel homeViewModel)
  {
    authViewModel.AuthenticationPassed += OnAuthenticationSuccessfull;

    this.Pages = new Dictionary<string, IPageViewModel>()  
    { 
      { nameof(AuthViewModel), authViewModel }, 
      { nameof(HomeViewModel), homeViewModel }
    };

    this.SelectedPage = this.Pages[nameof(AuthViewModel)];
  }

  public OnAuthenticationSuccessfull(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    (sender as AuthViewModel).AuthenticationPassed -= OnAuthenticationSuccessfull;

    this.SelectedPage = this.Pages[nameof(HomeViewModel)];
  }
}

class AuthViewModel
{
  public event EventHandler AuthenticationPassed { get; }

  ...
}
```

Comment: I tested this version with my code, but it causes an error. A circular dependency error.
Right now the loginM is injected into the mainVM and the mainVM is injected in the loginVM through the Navigator, making it so that one depends on the other. Even though the objects of both authVM and mainVM should just be referenced, the service builder doesn't like it.

Comment: Yeah, it's because you want each view models to navigate to each other. Ech view model has to know the MainViewModel while at the same time the MainViewModel knows each view model. I personally would never do that. I would only have the MainViewModel do the navigation. For example LoginViewModel should not know to select other view models. LoginViewModel could expose a LoginSuccessfull event, to which the MainViewModel listens to. When the even is raised the MainViewModel can select the next view model. I changed the answer to provide a simplified example of a solution I actually used before.

Comment: This worked, I didn't know about events but I can see how this can be really useful now. Thanks a lot for the help. You also said that this design isn't good, I did see a couple of other ways to do this, but I wasn`t able to tell which would be more fit, one particular way that seemed to be very common was using a viewmodel locator, a separate static container for vms, but also people were saying that this was an anti-pattern to DI so I felt it would not be good.

Comment: Very good decision not to use Service Locator. Also don't use Singleton. Instead prefer shared instance that is injected to the class. Static classes or static references that are not private can be very difficult. You will see a lot of smelling code (and tutorials) where the author passes around a static IoC container or a database connection reference.

Comment: Events are a very important concept. But make sure to unregister your event handlers to prevent memory leaks. [Fighting Common WPF Memory Leaks with dotMemory](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/)

Comment: [Weak Event Patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).